# How to grep inside a specific file in tar.gz without extracting?

Tags: bash, grep, tar

I'm looking for a command that can perform a grep operation in a specific file contained in a tar.gz archive.

Example:

file: archive.tar.gz, which ​contains:

```
fileA.txt
fileB.txt
fileC.txt
```

I want to grep only inside fileA.txt, not in the other two, without extract the files from the original archive, with only one command.

Is it possible?

I have tried:

```
for f in /path/*.gz; do
    tar -xzf "$f" --to-command='grep -Hn --label="$TAR_ARCHIVE/$TAR_FILENAME" pattern || true'
done
```

This command performs the grep in all files included in the archive, but this is not exactly what I need. I need a command that greps only in the file I want to search in.

Comment: It's worth noting that tar.gz files don't offer random access, so accessing a file in the middle of a tar.gz necessarily involves decompressing all preceding files.

Comment: essentially a duplicate of this [grep from tar.gz without extracting \[faster one\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13983365). Too bad `zgrep` doesn't receive a file name

Answer (score 18):

Tell `tar` which file it should process inside the archive:

```
for f in /path/*.gz; do
  tar -xzf "$f" --to-command='grep -Hn --label="$TAR_ARCHIVE/$TAR_FILENAME" pattern || true' fileA.txt
done
```

(`fileA.txt` at the end of the `tar` command).

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict the files that should be extracted by tar.

Assuming you use GNU tar, use the `--to-stdout` option. It is easier then passing a correctly quoted command.

```
for TAR_ARCHIVE in /path/*.gz; do
  TAR_FILENAME="fileA.txt"
  tar -xzf "$TAR_ARCHIVE" --to-stdout "$TAR_FILENAME" | grep -Hn --label="$TAR_ARCHIVE/$TAR_FILENAME" pattern
done
```

Comment: `$TAR_ARCHIVE` and `$TAR_FILENAME` are magic envvars `tar` sets with `--to-command`. With `--to-stdout`, you need to fill them in manually

Comment: If you're doing this because it's easier to type interactively, presumably you'd just leave out the `--label` part, or at least simplify it to just the tar file name.

Answer (score 1):

[ugrep](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep) searches tar.gz files with option `-z`.