# BASH: How to check if a file with a specific content is inside a png image

Tags: bash, zip, png

I have recently found a way to put files inside a PNG image without destroying the image using `cat example.png example.7z > example-combined.png`, which also works with standard ZIP archives. This puts the files inside the archive into the png file and stores that in the new PNG file which still shows the original image but if opened with e.g. 7zip reveals the files inside.

I want to know if there's a way to check if e.g. a text file named verified.txt with the text "I am Lampe2020" is inside that PNG file's archive section. Is that maybe possible without unpacking the whole thing, to make it quicker and less hard drive intensive?

Yes, I've seen [How to grep inside a specific file in tar.gz without extracting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645447/how-to-grep-inside-a-specific-file-in-tar-gz-without-extracting), but I am not sure if there's a way to do that with a PNG as I can't use `tar` for a PNG archive.

Comment: Isn't the point of a zip file that you *don't* have to extract the whole thing in order to get to a particular file because there is a directory at the end, unlike a tar file? It seems like standard unzip used normally works fine for this (e.g. `unzip example-combined.zip verified.txt`), but then you wouldn't have asked the question, so I'm not sure what the constraints are here.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I want to create a universal bash script which 1. takes a PNG, 2. searches for the specified file, 3. checks if the specified file's content equals a given expected content

Comment: To look for content, try `grep`. Names of files in an archive are part of the *content* of that archive, so it should work for that, too. Anything more complicated than that will probably require extracting the file. If  ``7zip`` works, why don’t you just use that? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Maybe you should think about your problem a little more.  Imagine that you’re in the same room with an expert, explain your problem to them, try to anticipate what questions a stranger will ask, and answer them. (It may help to use a rubber duck or a teddy bear.) If you (and your ‘‘friend’’) haven’t solved the problem after that, maybe you’ll at least be prepared to clarify your question.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I am not used to 7zip's CLI, but I'll look at it...

Comment: Maybe explain what you really want to do: Attach some metadata to an image? If so, that's a *bad* way to do it.

Comment: @U.Windl This is just an example use for such a piece of code. I could also store other types of files hidden away inside PNGs and check for their content. It isn't about metadata, it's more like checking if a file has been edited properly or at all and there are much more ideas that could come up once I have the ability to check for a file's content inside the PNG archive. But if there's no other way of doing it than I'll just unpack it, check it and delete the temporary file.